# Multi-profile (ESM format) Cucumber configuration file not quite working

Tags: javascript, cucumber, es6-modules, cucumberjs

I have the following configuration file for `Cucumber`:

```js
const common = {
  // ...common settings here
};

module.exports = {
  ci: {
    ...common,
    format: [
      "progress",
    ],
  },
  default: {
    ...common,
    format: [
      "progress-bar",
    ],
  },
};
```

This works flawlessly. I can specify any of the defined profiles, etc. I'm looking migrate, if possible, the same configuration file into [ESM format](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/configuration.md), but I just don't quite understand how to make the `default` profile work. If I do:

```js
export default {
  ci: { /* ... */ },
  default: { /* ... */ },
};
```

...and place `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, it stops working and the configuration is not understood anymore.

Can anyone spot what's the catch there? Would be great a small explanation if this can be done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was initially confused by the `default` keyword ;)

This is a working (ESM) configuration with multiple profiles:

```js
const common = {
  /* ... */
};

export const ci = {
  ...common,
  format: [
    "progress",
  ],
};

export default {
  ...common,
  format: [
    "progress-bar",
  ],
};
```